# Add new configuration to App.config at runtime

Tags: c#, xml, configuration, app-config

I have a file (MyFile.dll.config) which is an XML code. I want to add that file's nodes to the current `App.config` at runtime. I want to read the XML file then check if the nodes exists and if not, add them and refresh the `configuration node in App.config` to be able to use the new config.
The available nodes in the file that I want to add them are (`basicHttpBinding` and `endpoints`)

I wrote the following code but I don't know how to complete it.

```
        Configuration AppDllConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(this.GetType().Assembly.Location);
        AppSettingsSection myDllConfigAppSettings = (AppSettingsSection)AppDllConfig.GetSection("client");

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(MyFilePath);
        XmlNodeList xmlnodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/configuration/client/endpoint");


        AppDllConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("configuration");
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: In the general case it is impossible in runtime to change the config file located in the application folder. Because an application running without admin rights can't write to the Program Files folder. Therefore, you can only change/add the user settings. For example `AppDllConfig.AppSettings.Settings.Add("basicHttpBinding", "some binding");`

Comment: User settings are stored separately in the AppData folder in the user profile.The app has access to it.